# List box adding and remove with same index

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

### [DEMO](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/qBBWvEO)

In my project, I used a custom Listbox. It's working correctly at one side. If I remove from Left Sidebox, I need to Place that Old Position at the Right side.

```
$('#items li').click(function() {      
        var selected = [];
        selected.push($(this).html());            
         $(this).remove();        
        generateOptionElements(selected, '#selected');
    });

   
     populateItems('#items li');

    //populate items box with arr
    function populateItems(arr, targetMultiSelect) {
        arr.sort();
        generateOptionElements(arr, targetMultiSelect);
    }

//create option elements
function generateOptionElements(arr, targetMultiSelect) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('li');    

      
         option.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",arr[i]);
        $(targetMultiSelect).append(option);

         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main pont of the snippet below is that you should create an **Array** of **Objects** and manipulate that in JS, and only output the resulting **HTML**. It's better than manipulating the **DOM**.

```js
// Array of Objects - the questions and answers and other
// needed information
const questions = [{
    position: 0,
    side: 1,
    q: "0Animals giving birth to young ones:",
    a: ["Oviparous", "Oviviviparous", "Viviparous", "Both a and b"]
  },
  {
    position: 1,
    side: 1,
    q: "1Animals giving birth to young ones:",
    a: ["Oviparous", "Oviviviparous", "Viviparous", "Both a and b"]
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    side: 1,
    q: "2Animals giving birth to young ones:",
    a: ["Oviparous", "Oviviviparous", "Viviparous", "Both a and b"]
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    side: 1,
    q: "3Animals giving birth to young ones:",
    a: ["Oviparous", "Oviviviparous", "Viviparous", "Both a and b"]
  },
  {
    position: 4,
    side: 1,
    q: "4Animals giving birth to young ones:",
    a: ["Oviparous", "Oviviviparous", "Viviparous", "Both a and b"]
  },
]

// adding the created HTML to the DOM
const populateSides = questions => {

  // filling out left and right sides
  document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = questionListHtml(questions.filter(e => e.side === 1))
  document.getElementById('left').innerHTML = questionListHtml(questions.filter(e => e.side === -1))

  // adding click event listener to each question
  document.querySelectorAll('.question').forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      questions.find(el => el.position === Number(e.getAttribute('data-order'))).side *= -1
      populateSides(questions)
    })
  })

}

// template for the list
const questionListHtml = questions => {
  let html = ''
  html += '<ol>'
  questions.forEach(e => {
    html += `<li class="question" data-order="${e.position}">${singleQuestion(e)}</li>`
  })
  html += '</ol>'
  return html
}

// template for the single question
const singleQuestion = q => {
  let html = ''
  html += `${q.q}`
  html += `<ol>`
  q.a.forEach(e => {
    html += `<li>${e}</li>`
  })
  html += `</ol>`
  return html
}

populateSides(questions)
```

```css
#left {
  background: red;
}

#right {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col left">
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```